# How to wait for a rollout to complete in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

As part of our CI pipeline, we have a deployment script for a number of web services that looks something like this:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment1.yml
kubectl apply -f deployment2.yml
```

The problem is that the next stage of the pipeline sometimes fails because the services are not ready by the time it starts.

I would like to add a line in the script that says something like:

```
Wait until all deployments are in the Ready state, or fail if more than 30 seconds has elapsed.
```

I thought that the following would work but unfortunately it seems that the timeout flag is not available:

```
kubectl rollout status deployment deployment1 --timeout=30s
kubectl rollout status deployment deployment2 --timeout=30s
```

I don't want to run "kubectl rollout status" without a timeout as that will cause our build to hang if there is a failure in one of the deployments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution that works well. Set the property `.spec.progressDeadlineSeconds` to a value such as 30 (default is 600 or ten minutes) and `kubectl rollout status deployment` will wait for this amount of time before displaying an error message and exiting with a non zero exit code:

```
$ kubectl rollout status deploy/nginx
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new replicas have been updated...
error: deployment "nginx" exceeded its progress deadline
```

Documentation is here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment

Comment: Note: It doesn't wait till old pods are terminated and new pods are running. So, technically it doesn't wait till the rollout is literally "complete".

Answer (score 14):

Recent versions of `kubectl` do support a timeout option:

```
$ kubectl create -f ds-overlaytest.yml
daemonset.apps/overlaytest created
$ kubectl rollout status ds/overlaytest --timeout=10s
Waiting for daemon set spec update to be observed...
error: timed out waiting for the condition
$
```

Check out the `kubectl` reference on how to use this option:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-status-em-

Comment: In which version specifically was the timeout parameter introduced? Could you point to where this parameter is documented?

Comment: It's in `v1.25.3` , I didn't check the changelog to see when it was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly handle this with pure bash i.e.:

```
ATTEMPTS=0
ROLLOUT_STATUS_CMD="kubectl rollout status deployment/myapp -n namespace"
until $ROLLOUT_STATUS_CMD || [ $ATTEMPTS -eq 60 ]; do
  $ROLLOUT_STATUS_CMD
  ATTEMPTS=$((attempts + 1))
  sleep 10
done
```

This is specified in this [blog](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/updating-kubernetes-deployment-and-waiting-it-roll-out-shell-script)

However, I do not believe there is a Kubernetes Native way to wait for a deployments rollout, you could possibly accheive this with hooks in [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/) or [Webhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#what-are-admission-webhooks) if you want to get really fancy

Comment: `kubectl rollout status deployment` already does the wait. Op was asking if he can specify a specific timeout to wait instead of the default 10minutes.